Palo Alto Policy Issue: A port is Allowed Despite Restrictive Policy
I’m running into a strange issue on our Palo Alto firewall and could use some advice.
We have a security policy set up to allow traffic only on Ports 21 (FTP) and 22 (SSH). The Application field is set to any, and the Service field explicitly limits traffic to Ports 21 and 22.
However, I noticed the firewall is allowing traffic on Port 6667 (commonly associated with IRC). This doesn’t make sense to me, as Port 6667 isn’t part of the allowed services in this policy, so I was expecting it to be blocked.
I’ve already double-checked the policy rule order, and there are no broader rules overriding this one. The logs show the traffic is being allowed and identified as FTP, which seems odd given the port number.
Could this be related to how the any Application field works, or is there something else I’m missing?
